# Simplfying with Log and Exp functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Short question, I have:

$
\log \left(0.617424 e^{-1.19761 (W-0.427026)^2}\right)-\log \left(0.617424 e^{-1.19761 (0.116019\, -W)^2}\right)
$

`W` is real and positive. Now I want just that Mathematica outputs:

$-8.49684100856507^{-10} W^2+0.744933 W-0.202266$

I tried already to use

```
Simplify[%]

FullSimplify[%]

Assuming[W>0,Simplify[%]]

Assuming[{W>0, W elem Reals},Simplify[%]]
```

and a lot of other operations, but nothing worked out well. I understand that Mathematicas tries sometimes to keep exp-function, because it's easier to use them later, but instead of a linear function??

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `PowerExpand` to do the `Log[Exp]` reduction:

```
Simplify[PowerExpand[expr]]
(* -0.202265 + 0.74493 W *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell Mathematica that it has to use a simple rule (it is not applied automatically because of it makes the expression more complicated):

```
exp=Log[0.617424 Exp[-1.19761(W-0.427026)^2]] - Log[0.617424 Exp[-1.19761(0.116019-W)^2]]

Assuming[{W\[Element]Reals},Simplify[exp /. Log[a_ b_] :> Log[a]+Log[b]]]

(* -0.202265 + 0.74493 W *)
```

Comment: Not that straightforward as I expected, but thank you! :-)

Comment: I completely agree; @John Doty's answer is as it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try `FullSimplify` with assumptions.

```
expr = Log[0.617424 Exp[-1.19761 (W - 0.427026)^2]] - Log[0.617424 Exp[-1.19761 (0.116019 - W)^2]];

Assuming[W > 0, FullSimplify[exp]]

(* -0.202265 + 0.74493 W *)
```